# hwiOAuthBundle error on getting picture from facebook

Tags: facebook, symfony-2.3, hwioauthbundle

I'd configure a oAuth connection with the official documentation. All works except getting the profile picture from facebook.

The front redirects the valid user to a custom user-bundle register (need more data)

The weird part: When I try to use "infos_url" param, it redirects the autenticated user to the original register form, not the custom one. Either use the custom FOSUserProvider that gets the data.

any ideas?